# Wann müssen Nomen zusammengeschrieben werden?

Tags: single-word-request, noun

Ich habe gelernt, dass ich auf Deutsch immer mehrere Nomen zusammenschreiben kann.  Ich gebe das Beispiel *Firmaprojekten*:

> Der Mitarbeiter war für mehrere Firmaprojekte verantwortlich.

Meine Meinung ist, dass ich die zwei Namen zusammenschreiben kann, aber das Wort *"Firmaprojekten"* ist als nicht richtig in der Worddokumentprüfung markiert.

*"Firma Projekten"* ist als richtig genommen.
Kann jemand sagen warum?

Comment: Hinweis: Word ist mit zusammengesetzten Nomen meist gnadenlos überfordert. Die einzeln kennt es und markiert sie daher nicht.

Comment: Im vorliegenden Fall liegt Word aber (fast) richtig: "Firma" und "Projekt" gibt es, "Firmaprojekt" nicht. Dass Zusammensetzungen i.d.R. nur mit Zusammenschreibung oder Bindestrich erlaubt sind, damit ist Word allerdings offensichtlich überfordert.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Die Regeln, mit denen man aus zwei Nomen (Substantiven) ein neues Nomen bilden kann, sind eigentlich zu kompliziert, als dass man sie hier vollständig beschreiben könnte. Ich möchte es dennoch so einfach wie möglich erklären.

In vielen Fällen kann man die zwei Nomen einfach zusammenschreiben:

> - Brief + Träger → Briefträger
> - Fuß + Ball → Fußball

Manchmal muss man aber auch einen [Fugenlaut](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut) zwischen den Nomen einfügen, damit sich das zusammengeschriebene Wort besser aussprechen lässt:

> - Abfahrt + Zeit → Abfahrt**s**zeit
> - Arbeit + Amt → Arbeit**s**amt

Und in wieder anderen Fällen muss man die Endung des ersten Nomens weglassen oder nach bestimmten Regeln ändern:

> - Mühle + Rad → Mühlrad
> - Bund + Bank → Bund**es**bank (entstanden aus dem Genitiv *des Bund**es** Bank*)
> - Firma + Projekt → Firm**en**projekt

Auf jeden Fall ist aber ein zusammengesetztes Wort immer zusammenzuschreiben (zum Beispiel *Firmenprojekt* statt *Firmen Projekt*).
Doch auch hier gibt es wieder Regeln, insbesondere in Verbindung mit [Bindestrichen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viertelgeviertstrich#Bindestrich), die beschreiben, wie man das macht.

Comment: +1 for mentioning "Genitiv"

Comment: Der Lesbarkeit halber ist es in bestimmten Fällen auch erlaubt (und sinnvoll), die Nomen nicht einfach aneinanderzuschreiben, sondern nur per Bindestrich zu verbinden. Beispielsweise Sauerstoff-Flasche statt Sauerstoffflasche. Dies sind aber Ausnahmefälle.  Auch sind Fugenlaute teilweise regional unterschiedlich, aber das gehört zur erwähnten Komplexität des Themas.

Comment: @Chieron, siehe letzten Satz.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Ich schlage vor: Pfannkuchen, Palmwedel, Mühlrad.

Answer (score 3):

Das Wort heißt "Firmenprojekt"! Es gibt kein "Firmaprojekt". In der Beugung heißt es dann z.B. "in den Firmenprojekten".